# How to correctly retrieve the SQL INSERT code from a .sql file into the @BeforeEach annotated method of a Spring Boot Junit class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am working on a Spring Boot application and I am finding some difficulties with the following topic:

I have this JUnit test class testing a service:

package com.fivebits.gestionale.service;

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import com.fivebits.gestionale.model.Client;

@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class ClientServiceTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
    
    @Value("${sql.script.create.client}")
    private String sqlAddClients;
    
    @Value("${sql.script.delete.client}")
    private String sqlDeleteClient;
    
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setupDatabase() throws ScriptException, SQLException {
        jdbc.execute(sqlAddClients);
        
    }
    
    @Test
    void getClientsListTest() {
        
        List<Client> clientsList = clientService.getClientsList();
    
        // Check that this is not an empty list:
        assertFalse(clientsList.isEmpty());
        
    }
    
     @AfterEach
        public void setupAfterTransaction() {
            jdbc.execute(sqlDeleteClient);
        }
    

}
```

In particular it contains this method that is executed before all the test methods to set up the DB content:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setupDatabase() throws ScriptException, SQLException {
    jdbc.execute(sqlAddClients);
    
}
```

And here it is my problem. I am calling this **jdbc.execute(sqlAddClients);** in order to insert demo data into my DB.

As you can see this clas referers to this properties file (and I am using the **sql.script.create.client** property in order to retrieve the SQL statment to populate my DB.

```
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
```

Into this **application-test.properties** I have something like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gestionale_interno_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mypswd
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

server.port=8080


sql.script.create.client=classpath:sql/inserClient.sql
#sql.script.create.client=INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email) VALUES ('Cliente 1', 'VAT001', 'Indirizzo Cliente 1', 'cliente1@email.com');


sql.script.delete.client=DELETE FROM client
```

The thing that interest me is this line:

```
sql.script.create.client=classpath:sql/inserClient.sql
```

NOTE: mocking the SQL insert statement (as done in the following commented line) it works fine. I am trying to avoid to put the SQL statement directly into this property file in order to mantein it clean..so I am trying to retrieve it in the previous way directly from this **sql/inserClient.sql** file. This one:

[image]

This file contains the following SQL insert statement:

```
-- Inserisci il primo cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 1', 'VAT001', 'Indirizzo Cliente 1', 'cliente1@email.com');

-- Inserisci il secondo cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 2', 'VAT002', 'Indirizzo Cliente 2', 'cliente2@email.com');

-- Inserisci il terzo cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 3', 'VAT003', 'Indirizzo Cliente 3', 'cliente3@email.com');

-- Inserisci il quarto cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 4', 'VAT004', 'Indirizzo Cliente 4', 'cliente4@email.com');

-- Inserisci il quinto cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 5', 'VAT005', 'Indirizzo Cliente 5', 'cliente5@email.com');

-- Inserisci il sesto cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 6', 'VAT006', 'Indirizzo Cliente 6', 'cliente6@email.com');

-- Inserisci il settimo cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 7', 'VAT007', 'Indirizzo Cliente 7', 'cliente7@email.com');

-- Inserisci l'ottavo cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 8', 'VAT008', 'Indirizzo Cliente 8', 'cliente8@email.com');

-- Inserisci il nono cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 9', 'VAT009', 'Indirizzo Cliente 9', 'cliente9@email.com');

-- Inserisci il decimo cliente
INSERT INTO client (name, vat_number, address, email)
VALUES ('Cliente 10', 'VAT010', 'Indirizzo Cliente 10', 'cliente10@email.com');
```

the problem is that running my JUnit test class, it is going into error when this method is performed:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setupDatabase() throws ScriptException, SQLException {
    jdbc.execute(sqlAddClients);
    
}
```

**NOTE:** using the debugger I can see that the content of the **sqlAddClients** is this string: **classpath:sql/inserClient.sql**
So it is not containing all the SQL statment into my **inserClient.sql** file.

This is the exception obtained when I try to execute this line **jdbc.execute(sqlAddClients);**:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [classpath:sql/inserClient.sql]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:398)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:434)
    at com.fivebits.gestionale.service.ClientServiceTest.setupDatabase(ClientServiceTest.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:78)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$23(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:505)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "classpath"
  Posizione: 1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:335)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:292)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:425)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:383)
    ... 76 more
```

What is wrong in my approach? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Remove the methods and simply add `@Sql("classpath:sql/inserClient.sql")`. See the documentation for mor einformation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html. In short it is supported by Spring Test and you don't really need to write the before/after test methods.

Comment: I annoted my test method with this Sql annotation but I am obtaining this exception (I suppose that the specified path could be wrong). Some further idea?: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [sql/inserClient.sql]

Comment: Solved.Tnx a lot @M.Deinum If you put as answer I will be happu to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing SQL script before/after a test method is supported out-of-the-box by the Spring Test Framework. For this you can use the [`@Sql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html) annotation. You can place it on the class or method (or a combination of both). Using the `executionPhase` you can specify when to execute the SQL (before or after the method execution).

```java
@Sql("classpath:/sql/insertClient.sql")
```

Will execute this script for you.